# When do chained linq queries execute sql?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Linq to SQL doesn't actually run the sql until the result is enumerated, that I get.  However, in this example below when does that happen?  Are these all bundled up into one giant query some how or does this seriously pull most of two tables into memory so it can execute the last line?

```
result = _repository.LocationHandler.Locations(id).Where(x => x.IsActive);

paymentServiceProfiles = _repository.Context.PaymentServiceProfiles.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && x.IsActive);

terminals = _repository.TerminalHandler.Terminals().Where(x => x.IsActive && x.PaymentServiceProfiles.Intersect(paymentServiceProfiles).Any());

result = result.Where(x => terminals.Count(y => y.LocationId == x.Id) > 0);
```

Comment: You could always use a profiler or dump the query from the context to find out :)

Comment: Somewhere after the code you have (if ever).

Comment: (Assuming those repository properties all return `IQueryable`)

Comment: LINQpad can show you the resulting SQL if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All four lines are just preparing 'one big' query. If you will not use the result data later, this query won't be executed at all. But, as other have mentioned, using SQL Server Profiler (SSMS => Tools => Sql Server Profiler) is the best way how to answer the questions like this by yourself.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this is on a community server so the profile was crammed with stuff unrelated to me and there doesn't appear to be any filters so finding my calls (not knowing when or what they look like) is pretty much impossible.

Comment: @dsmithpl13 Try LINQpad to find out